# How to order itens with StaggeredGridLayoutManager

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-layout

I'm creating a grid as you can see in the image below.

Input list: {"Position 0", "Position 1", "Position 2", "Position 3", "Position 4", .....}

[image]

The problem is that, I would like a menu with two types of components.

**small -->** Position 0 in the image

**Huge -->** Position 2 in the image

So, when my adapter created the item from *position 4*, it is out of order.

**Expected output:**

Position 1, Position 2, Position 3

Position 4, Position 5, Position 6

```
public class SampleRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SampleViewHolders> {
private List<ItemObject> itemList;
private Context context;

public SampleRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context,
                                 List<ItemObject> itemList) {
    this.itemList = itemList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public SampleViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.book_list_item, null);
    SampleViewHolders rcv = new SampleViewHolders(layoutView);
    return rcv;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SampleViewHolders holder, int position) {
    holder.bookName.setText(itemList.get(position).getName()  + position);

    if (position % 2 == 0) {
        holder.itemView.setMinimumHeight(250);
    } else {
        holder.itemView.setMinimumHeight(300);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.itemList.size();
}
```

}

Comment: Set `spanCount` like this **`GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);`**

Comment: Hi, the problem is that height from elements are not the same.

Comment: what dose setMinimumHeight method dose ?

Comment: @JustASimpleLineOfCode the issue he's having is of the order of items being changed from a logical perspective due to the adapter adjusting the next row in between the available span area

Comment: Exactly, can you see any solution for the problem? I don't know what is the best way to build this layout.

Comment: @JustASimpleLineOfCode have you fix this requirement? I just need the same idea.

Answer (score 2):

you should add the listener for lookup size

```
mGridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
  @Override
   public int getSpanSize(int position) {
    return //do your logic here
  }
});
```

if you want to add the span count

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, //count);
```

Comment: Hello, Is it possible to change the *row* span? With this logic I can change only the *col* span. The height of elements should be diferent.

Comment: you want to change the width or the height of the item?

Comment: The height, for example ( Item A height ->X, Item B height X/3)